"Failed to launch the design tool server process:
Suddenly all my controls in my "Amiga" project fail to load the designer ....
There is no clue for which the problem is.
What should I do?
I've tried to clean and rebuild the solution, I've looked at the code and found nothing suspicious..
I'm lost here.
Any help will be appreciated.
the error code:

enter code here
Instances of this error (1)

Hide Call Stack

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.TplExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<-ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__27.MoveNext()

I tried to clean the solution and rebuild it and it did not work.

Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as text rather than as a screenshot.  See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? for why. For help on formatting see How do I format my code blocks?. A [mcve] showing exactly how to reproduce your problem would maximize your chances of getting useful answers here; see [ask] for more.

Is this about Visual Studio? Which version?

Absent more details we can't answer your question.  But the following questions do include the same error message: VS2022 .Net 6 winform app - Designer not loading and Can't open WinForms forms with Infragistics UltraWinGrid control anymore in Visual Studio designer after moving to .NET 8.
